# Making facebook embedded page disappear on a certain width

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am trying to build in a facebook feed that disppears when the page get's too thin.

```
<div id="facebook">
    <div id="fb-root" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="margin:0;padding:0;"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/novakovtech/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="700" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
      <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/novakovtech/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/novakovtech/">Novakov Tech</a>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That was my html
Here is my CSS:

```
#facebook{
  width:40% !important;
  float:left!important;
}

@media(max-width:1300px){
  #facebook #fb-page #fb_iframe_widget #fb-xfbml-parse-ignore #fb-root{
    visibility:hidden !important;
    display:none !important;
  }
}
```

I tried to make every class possible have a display none, but nothing worked so far. I am getting frustrated so thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not utilize bootstrap classes for this

```
<div id="facebook" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  ---
  ---
</div>
```

ex: `hidden-xs` will hide div in xtra small screen (<768px) like mobile

you can learn more here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: glad I could help